# Scanning Items into SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-form, attachments

Is it possible to scan documents directly into sharepoint as an attachment to a list form? We are using SharePoint online.

Answer (score 0):

I've had pretty good luck with [KnowledgeLake](https://www.knowledgelake.com/intelligent-content-delivery-sharepoint) but there are plenty of other options.

[SharePoint Scan and OCR App](https://store.office.com/en-001/app.aspx?assetid=WA104295830&ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US&appredirect=false) - seems to be able to take documents already in SharePoint and convert them.

[Aquaforest Searchlight](https://www.aquaforest.com/en/searchlight.asp)

[ABBYY](https://www.abbyy.com/en-us/solutions/sharepoint/features/)

Most of these have OCR software too so you can make the PDFs searchable once they are in SharePoint.